# Jquery Ajax call return an error but work with curl

Tags: jquery, ajax, debugging

I do a ajax call with jquery

```
<form class="navbar-form" role="search">
     <div class="input-group">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Rechercher" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
         <div class="input-group-btn">
             <button id="lodgerSearch" type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
         </div>
     </div>
</form>

$('#lodgerSearch').on('click', function (e) {
  var searchParam = $('#srch-term').val();
  var url = "http://localhost:8080/lodgers/search";

  if(searchParam!=""){
    url = "http://localhost:8080/lodgers/search?searchTemp=" + searchParam; 
  }

  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
        alert(data);
        // do something
        alert("sucess");
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, status) {
        // error handler
        alert("error " + jqXHR + " -  " + status);
    }
  });
});
```

with the ajax call in the browser I get this message

```
error [object Object] -  error
```

my controller in java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/lodgers/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<LodgerSearch> getAllLogders(@RequestParam(value = "inactiveLodger", required = false) boolean inactiveLodger, @RequestParam(value = "searchTerm", defaultValue="") String searchTerm) {
    return lodgerService.searchLodger(inactiveLodger, searchTerm);
}
```

If i do curl localhost:8080/lodgers/search
I get the expected result

```
[{"lodgerId":1,"firstName":"Marc","lastName":"Collin","birthdate":"2015-06-17","nas":null,"nam":null,"buildingRoom":null},{"lodgerId":2,"firstName":"yvan","lastName":"Dubois","birthdate":"2015-06-18","nas":null,"nam":null,"buildingRoom":null}]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in parameters concatenation.

This code:

```
if(searchParam!=""){
  url = "http://localhost:8080/lodgers/searchTemp?" + searchParam; 
}
```

doesn't call http://localhost:8080/lodgers/search, it calls http://localhost:8080/lodgers/searchTemp (not a parameter).

when you use curl, you passing the right url so it returns ok.

Change the above code to

```
if(searchParam!=""){
  url = "http://localhost:8080/lodgers/search?searchTemp=" + searchParam; 
}
```

include the other parameter as well if you like.

Comment: don't fix, because i my used i don't used any value... so it was empty. when i click button, i see my alert box with the url: http://localhost:8080/lodgers/search. browser move me to url: index.html?srch-term= it's seem my html form cause issue.

Comment: what alert box shows you that ? there are 3 alert boxes in the code. Considering sucess method is not called 2 of them are out. The other one is the error alert box which doesn't show the url.
Anyway, please remove the searchParam "if statement" just to be sure it's not doing anything.